# Get associated products Price and Size from configurable product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes, configurable-product

I want to have in the product view page and in the category page a list with all size attribute and price for each configurable product. I use this code to display the size and is work perfect but I need to get the price too. How I can add the price for associated products in the following code.

Thank you

```
$ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds($_product->getId()); //get the children ids through a simple query
$attrs  = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product);
foreach($attrs as $attr) {
    if(0 == strcmp("size", $attr['attribute_code'])) {
        $options    = $attr['values'];
        foreach($options as $option) {
            print "{$option['store_label']}<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

I need to be something like in this image:

[image]

**Edit:**
I can get simple products prices with the following code but how I can have Size and Price foreach simple product?

```
if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
    $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
    $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
    foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){
        echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($simple_product->getPrice());
    }
endif;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

considered `size` as attribute code and `$simple_collection` as simple products data.

```
    $_sized = array();
    $_size_id = array();
    foreach ($simple_collection as $simple_product) {              

      $label = $simple_product->getAttributeText('size');
      $_sized[] = $label;

      if (!isset($_size_id[$label])) {
        $_size_id[$label] = $simple_product->getData('size');
      }
    }

    //apply uniqueness
    $_final_sizes = array_unique($_sized);
```

EDITED ANSWER

```
    $j=0;
    foreach ($simple_collection as $simple_product) {
      $label = $simple_product->getAttributeText('size');
      $_sized[] = $label;

      if (!isset($_size_id[$label])) {
        $_size_id[$j][] =$label;
        $_size_id[$j][] = Mage::helper('core')->currency($simple_product->getPrice());
$j++;
      }
    }

    echo '<pre>';print_r($_size_id); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: thank you but the prices for each attribute?

Comment: that you already have it i guess

Comment: No I don't have, this is my question, how I can get price for each option, because options is work with my first code and I need to add prices for each option

Comment: @RobertD check updated answer

Comment: @AA Why use both getAttributeText and simple_product->getData?